# Show that $g$ is injective

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

How can one show that if
$g(f(x))$ is injective and $f$ is surjective then $g$ is injective?

Here is my attempt:

$g(f(x))$ is injective, so

$$g(f(a))=g(f(b)) \iff f(a)=f(b).$$

$f$ is surjective, so $f(x)=y$.

So $y=y'$ such that $f(b)=y'$.

So $g$ is injective.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof is not correct. The injectivity of $g\circ f$ stands for $g(f(a))=g(f(b))\implies a=b$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $g(a)=g(b)$.

Since $f$ is surjective we can find $x,y$ such that $a=f(x)$ and $b=f(y)$.

Then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$.

The injectivity of $g\circ f$ now ensures that $x=y$ and consequently $a=f(x)=f(y)=b$.

Proved is now that $g$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. It might help to talk about the domains and codomains.

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$

Let $g:B \rightarrow C$...

then $g \circ f: A \rightarrow C$.

Let $a,b \in A$. Then, $g(f(x))$ being injective implies that if $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$, then $a=b$.

What you wrote actually assumes the result, namely the injectivity of $g$ since your $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are both in $B$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\neq b$. Observe that

$g(a) = g(f(x))$ for some $x$  and $g(b) = g(f(y))$ for some $y$ since $f$ is surjective.

Moreover, $g(f(x))\neq g(f(y))$ since $g(f)$ is injective.

Therefore $g(a) \neq g(b)$, and $g$ is injective.

**Remark**: You should spend some time on defining the domain and range of each of your funcions. I skipped that step here, but it is very important.

Comment: You spoiled it! haha

Comment: @AndresMejia I suppose so!